# Why can't I open the CSS Theme in Codenameone

Tags: css, codenameone

I was working on some changes to my CSS file and at the time of execution it sent me the error shown. I tried generating another CSS file and even put a minimum of code, but the problem persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the `.res` files from the project and rebuilding. Scroll up in the error log you see review it. There should be detailed explanations on what went wrong. I guess your CSS syntax has a problem which is why the resource file failed to generate.

Comment: I'm on Windows with Netbeans.
Delete the theme in the following path:
"C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\taxifataxi\common\target\classes"

When executing it does not create the theme and sends me the following error:
"Watching directories [C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\taxifataxi\common\src\main\java]
java.io.IOException: /theme.res not found"

Check other forums and it mentions that the problem is with a plugin that affects maven.

Comment: You need to scroll up in the console and see if these are other errors or warnings above it. For some reason the CSS file isn't translated to a resource file. I'm guessing there's a syntax error in the CSS. Not sure why it isn't failing the build. I suggest copying the whole error and pasting it in a gist then providing the link here...

Comment: I solved creating a new app. Thanks for the support.